# udp client server program c

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am writing a simple client and server program in C. I am able to send date from client to server. But, I am not able to send acknowledge from server to client.

```
/*******************udpserver.c*****************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Variable and structure definitions. */
    int sd, rc;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
    clientaddrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
    int serveraddrlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
    char buffer[100];
    char *bufptr = buffer;
    int buflen = sizeof(buffer);

    if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("UDP server - socket() error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("UDP server - socket() is OK\n");

    memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, serveraddrlen);
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(0);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if((rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, serveraddrlen)) < 0) {
        perror("UDP server - bind() error");
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    int addr_len = sizeof(serveraddr);
    if (getsockname(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &addr_len)<0) {
        perror("Error getting socket name.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Using IP %s and port %d\n", inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), ntohs(serveraddr.sin_port));
    printf("UDP server - Listening...\n");

    rc = recvfrom(sd, bufptr, buflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clientaddrlen);
    if(rc < 0) {
        perror("UDP Server - recvfrom() error");
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }

   printf("UDP Server received the following:\n \"%s\" message\n", bufptr);

   printf("UDP Server replying to the UDP client...\n");
   rc = sendto(sd, bufptr, buflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, clientaddrlen);
   if(rc < 0) {
       perror("UDP server - sendto() error");
       close(sd);
       exit(-1);
   }
   printf("UDP Server - sendto() is OK...\n");

   close(sd);
   exit(0);
}
```

My UDPClient program:

```
/****************udpclient.c********************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Variable and structure definitions. */
    int sd, rc;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
    int serveraddrlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
    char server[255];
    char buffer[100];
    char *bufptr = buffer;
    int buflen = sizeof(buffer);
    struct hostent *hostp;
    memset(buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
    /* 36 characters + terminating NULL */
    memcpy(buffer, "Hello! A client request message lol!", 37);

    if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("UDP Client - socket() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
        printf("UDP Client - socket() is OK!\n");

    if(argc != 3) {
        /*Use default hostname or IP*/
        printf("UDP Client - Usage <Server hostname or IP>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    hostp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(hostp == (struct hostent *)NULL) {
        printf("HOST NOT FOUND --> ");
        printf("h_errno = %d\n", h_errno);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        printf("UDP Client - gethostname() of the server is OK... \n");
        printf("Connected to UDP server\n");
    }
    memcpy(&serveraddr.sin_addr, hostp->h_addr, sizeof(serveraddr.sin_addr));

    rc = sendto(sd, bufptr, buflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    if(rc < 0) {
        perror("UDP Client - sendto() error");
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
        printf("UDP Client - sendto() is OK!\n");

    printf("Waiting a reply from UDP server...\n");

    rc = recvfrom(sd, bufptr, buflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, &serveraddrlen);

    if(rc < 0) {
        perror("UDP Client - recvfrom() error");
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("UDP client received the following: \"%s\" message\n", bufptr);
    }

    close(sd);
    exit(0);
}
```

When running the two programs, I am getting the following output:

UdpServer:

```
$ ./UdpServer
UDP server - socket() is OK
Using IP 0.0.0.0 and port 49932
UDP server - Listening...
UDP Server received the following:
"Hello! A client request message lol!" message
UDP Server replying to the UDP client...
UDP Server - sendto() is OK...
```

UdpClient:

```
$ ./UdpClient MyPC 49932 
UDP Client - socket() is OK!
UDP Client - gethostname() of the server is OK...
Connected to UDP server
UDP Client - sendto() is OK!
Waiting a reply from UDP server...
```

UdpClient program is stuck at this point. Could anyone please explain what the problem is?

Comment: According to me try to add sleep() in between while you are transmitting,receiving and acknowledging. So that it wont be overlapped or you can say that it will be in proper sync.

Comment: It works well, when I add sleep in server. Is there any other method?

Comment: sleep() provides synchronization. If you want another way around then try to implement locking mechanism (semaphores etc..) which will ensure that no deadlock will happen.

Comment: OT: The last arguments to `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` shall be of type `socklen_t` for the former and of type `socklen_t *` for the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to use `select()` to make the process wait until data is avaibale for reading:

```
...
{
  fd_set rfds;
  int retval;

  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(sd, &rfds);

  retval = select(sd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (retval == -1)
    perror("select()");
  else
    printf("Data is available for reading now.\n");

  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server and client are running on the same machine, give

`$ ./UdpClient localhost 49932`

instead of

`$ ./UdpClient MyPC 49932`

else
`$ ./UdpClient <server-IP-address> 49932`

Also in the server code,

`clientaddrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);`
should be
`int clientaddrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);`

But I guess that's just a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: I want my program to run on 2 different machines. So, I have added machine name